# Transaction Reverting with my smart contract

Tags: uniswap, defi

I am making a defi page using uniswap v2 router, but my transaction are reverting. Here is my swapToken.sol contract:-

Pls help me in this, to fix this issue.

Also link to the expolorer - https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x8270514797bd50e1caa66711bcc41a9680cf5c03d833afa75f2a3eec45bcb3cf

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol";
import "@uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol";


contract SwapToken {
    address private constant UNISWAP_ROUTER=0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address private SHM = 0xae49C37fc1C0487Fe1F3778570a496a9F01960AC ;
    address private WETH=0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;
    address constant TST= 0x5a1Cdd07b84EA4273283a717AD722c00EdE6E79E;
    IERC20 private weth = IERC20(WETH);
    IERC20 private tst = IERC20(TST);
    IERC20 private shm = IERC20(SHM);
    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapRouter;
    constructor(){
        uniswapRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(UNISWAP_ROUTER);
    }
    //Swap TST for SHM
    function swapTSTForSHM(
        uint amountOutDesired,
        uint amountInMax
    ) external returns (uint amountOut) {
        tst.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountInMax);
        tst.approve(address(uniswapRouter), amountInMax);

        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](3);
        path[0] = TST;
        path[1] = WETH;
        path[2] = SHM;

        uint[] memory amounts = uniswapRouter.swapTokensForExactTokens(
            amountOutDesired,
            amountInMax,
            path,
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp
        );

        // Refund TST to msg.sender
        if (amounts[0] < amountInMax) {
            tst.transfer(msg.sender, amountInMax - amounts[0]);
        }

        return amounts[2];
    }
    function swapSHMForTST(
        uint amountOutDesired,
        uint amountInMax
    ) external returns (uint amountOut) {
        shm.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amountInMax);
        shm.approve(address(uniswapRouter), amountInMax);

        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](3);
        path[0] = SHM;
        path[1] = WETH;
        path[2] = TST;

        uint[] memory amounts = uniswapRouter.swapTokensForExactTokens(
            amountOutDesired,
            amountInMax,
            path,
            msg.sender,
            block.timestamp
        );

        // Refund SHM to msg.sender
        if (amounts[0] < amountInMax) {
            shm.transfer(msg.sender, amountInMax - amounts[0]);
        }

        return amounts[2];
    }
}
```

Comment: I saw your post on upwork. Are you still having this issue?

Comment: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x8270514797bd50e1caa66711bcc41a9680cf5c03d833afa75f2a3eec45bcb3cf At first, you should deploy uniswap router and token contracts on mumbai testnet if you want to test it on testnet.
Please let me know if you need any help